# Custom validation error message in Swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have a Swagger definition for a Rest API, with [regex patterns](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern) for validation of fields in the request body. But when the validation fails, a default error message is thrown -
`{field}: must match {regex pattern}`. With regex pattern in the error message, it makes less sense to the end user. How to customise this message preferably by using Swagger? I could add a handler in Java for 400 Bad request exception and handle it there, but that will be the last option, to modify java code.

Comment: Do you want to get error message in the swagger UI or when actually using your API/service?

Comment: When actually using the API, basically the response of the API should have the error message.

Comment: What Java framework / middleware do you use?

Comment: Springboot version 2.7.5

Comment: I am looking for a way to show an error message in the swagger UI when a pattern match fails. Any suggestions